# no drb server is running, after ran "bundle exec rspec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following rubyonrails tutorial, then I stuck on http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-flavored-ruby#code:home_page_base_title

when I typed 'bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb'
got the following error

> no DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
>   FFFFFFFFF
>
> Failures:
>
> 1) Static pages Home page should have the h1 'Sample App'
>        Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/home'
>        ActionView::Template::Error:
>          undefined local variable or method `page' for #<#<Class:0x007fd991bb7610>:0x007fd9928d8290>
>        # ./app/helpers/application_helper.rb:6:in`full_title'
>        # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2444475768180965445_70286215048520'
>        # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:8:in`block (3 levels) in '

in .rspec file

> --colour
>   --drb

Do the errors come from guard, sport(in last part of chapter 3)??

Answer (score 1):

This probably wont help the OP anymore, but I had the same thing if the DRb server is not running it'll run in local process. For me the error was because I switched to postgresql (as per the end of chapter 3) and didn't start up the server. After I started the server, the test ran fine.

I hope that helps anyone who may end up here with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The warning indicates that spork wasn't running or couldn't be contacted (rspec uses drb to talk to spork) so rspec reverted to a normal run.

Your specs should pass whether run under spork or not though, so this is unlikely to be why they are failing, just why they are taking a few more seconds to fail.

Comment: Thanks. How can I fix the drb running and all the test passes